# Show that a homeomorphism is an open map

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I am struggling to show that a homeomorphism maps an open set to an open set. I have seen online the identity $$f(U) = (f^{-1})^{-1}(U)$$ but I get confused since consider $f(x)=2x$. $f(1,2)=(2,4)$ but $(f^{-1})^{-1}(1,2) = (1,2)$. Can someone please point out where I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Since, $f(x)=2x$, $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac x2$. Therefore,\begin{align}(f^{-1})^{-1}\bigl((1,2)\bigr)&=\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\middle|\,f^{-1}(x)\in(1,2)\right\}\\&=\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\middle|\,\frac x2\in(1,2)\right\}\\&=(1,4)\\&=f\bigl((1,2)\bigr).\end{align}

Comment: but isn't $f^{-1}(1,2) = (1/2,1)$ and then the pre-image of this is (1,2)?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My answer contains no reference to $f^{-1}\bigl((1,2)\bigr)$.

Comment: I believe I am getting confused as to what is the inverse and what is the pre image. Also on how to use the identity to get the a homeomorphism is an open map

Comment: The inverse of a function $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ is a function $g\colon B\longrightarrow A$ such that$$(\forall a\in A):g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=a\text{ and }(\forall b\in B):f\bigl(g(b)\bigr)=b.$$If $S\subset B$, $f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in S\}$. This is the pre-image of $S$ and it is defined even if $f$ has no inverse.

Comment: Can we at least be honest with the fact that $(f^{-1})^{-1}((1,2))$ is confusingly ambiguous notation? You can either parse it as „the preimage of $(1,2)$ under the function $f^{-1}$“ or „the image of $(1,2)$ under the function $(f^{-1})^{-1}$“.

Comment: In turns out that **if** $f$ has an inverse, then both meanings of $f^{-1}(S)$ (the one from my previous comment and the image of $S$ by the map $f^{-1}$) are the same set.

Comment: If there is something in my answer that you think that it is wrong, please tell me where it is.